# How to query the CouchDB data with the start date and end date

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

In my node application I am using the Cradle library to save the data in CouchDB.
Now I want to get the stored data with the specified start date and end date.
How can I do this. I have added design document as below. Is it correct?
How to pass my parameters to this function?

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.date) {
        var key = [doc.start, doc.end];
        emit(key, doc);
    }
}
```

Document Structure

```
       {
         "_id": "58113f948561d38b1eba8ba343432c45",
         "_rev": "1-be4f3d2fd93a8941659c73333941561d",
         "date": "2013-04-29T06:36:29.165Z",
         "name":"sdasd",
         "age":"20"
       }
```

I'm querying like below for the above design document

```
var startDate = '2013-04-27T08:41:23.559Z';
var endDate = '2013-04-29T08:41:23.559Z';

db.view('data/byDate', { key: [startDate, endDate] }, function(err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(doc.length);
    } else {
        console.log('Error '+err);
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems correct. What does not work exactly?

Comment: @Simon i have more documents between the specified date but i'm not getting any documents while using the above view statement.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your example document and your view do not match: You try to emit `doc.start` and `doc.end` but these fields are not present (hence the document will not be included in the view). Maybe you just want to emit `doc.date`? Like so:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.date) {
        emit(doc.date, doc);
    }
}
```